# dplyr inner_join with NAs on character columns

Tags: r, inner-join, dplyr

I have two equal data frames

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(3,2,1)
c <- c('a','b',NA)

df1 <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I would like to use `dplyr::inner_join` to

> "return all rows from x where there are matching values in y, and all columns from x and y" [dplyr documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf)

(which is everything as they are equal) but it doesn't seem to work with an `NA` in column `c` (type `chr`). Is this standard behaviour to not join on the `NA`s?

For example

```
library(dplyr)
> inner_join(df1, df2)
Joining by: c("a", "b", "c")
  a b c
1 1 3 a
2 2 2 b
```

doesn't join on the `NA`. However, I would like it to return the same as `merge`

```
> merge(df1, df2)
  a b    c
1 1 3    a
2 2 2    b
3 3 1 <NA>
```

Have I misunderstood how `inner_join` works in this instance and is this behaving as described?

**Further Detail**

`inner_join` matches `NA` on a numeric column

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(3,2,NA)
c <- c('a','b','c')

df1 <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> inner_join(df1, df2)
Joining by: c("a", "b", "c")
  a  b c
1 1  3 a
2 2  2 b
3 3 NA c
```

**Edit**

As @thelatemail points out, `inner_join` also works as `merge` when the `NA` is in a factor column

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, stringsAsFactors=T)
df2 <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, stringsAsFactors=T)
inner_join(df1, df2)
Joining by: c("a", "b", "c")
  a b    c
1 1 3    a
2 2 2    b
3 3 3 <NA>
```

**Edit 2**

Thanks to @shadow for pointing out this is a known issue [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1022) and [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/892)

Comment: Nice question and well presented examples. Interesting to note that `inner_join` also works as intended when using character data stored as `factor`s, e.g.: altering your first example `df1$c <- factor(df1$c); df2$c <- factor(df2$c); inner_join(df1,df2)`

Comment: This is a known issue. See [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1022) or [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/892)

Comment: Thanks @shadow , I'll keep an eye out for a fix.

Comment: Have you tried the latest dev version of dplyr? There was a similar issue with left_join which got fixed, so I'm assuming this one may have been fixed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was occurring in version 0.4.1. This is now fixed in version 0.4.2:

```
sessionInfo()
...
other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.2
...

> inner_join(df1, df2)
Joining by: c("a", "b", "c")
  a b    c
1 1 3    a
2 2 2    b
3 3 1 <NA>
```

Check with merge:

```
> merge(df1, df2)
  a b    c
1 1 3    a
2 2 2    b
3 3 1 <NA>

> all.equal(inner_join(df1, df2), merge(df1, df2))
Joining by: c("a", "b", "c")
[1] TRUE
```